# How to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}dx$ = $\int_0^1 \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

Here is a real analysis question from my practice sheet.

> Is $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}dx=\int_0^1 \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}dx?$$

My first thought was they are not equal since  $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$  doesn't converge uniformly.

But the solution in my sheet said this equality is correct because $$\frac{1}{2(n+1)} \le \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}dx \le \frac{1}{n+1}$$
This solution really confused me. Does anyone have ideas how to get this inequality and why it proves the question?

Comment: Note that $1 \leq 1 + x^{n}\leq 2$ so $x^{n}/2 \leq x^{n}/(1 + x^{n}) \leq x^{n}$ Now integrate. The LHS and RHS are both seen to be $0$. Hence the identity in question is proved. Note that uniform convergence is sufficient for such identities, but not necessary and the integral identity can be true without uniform convergence also.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh why not putting this into an answer?

Comment: @tired: request granted! You can now see from my long answer that I did not have time to type the answer so added a short but *helpful* comment.

Comment: I thought in general lim f(a_n) =f( lim a_n) given f is continuous at lim a_n .  Here f is the definite integral from 0 to 1. This is because the sequence can always be extended to a continuous function (and here nicely) and the composition of continous functions is continous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On request of @tired I am putting my comment as an answer.

---

Note that when $0 \leq x \leq 1$ then we have $$0 \leq x^{n} \leq 1$$ and hence $$1 \leq 1 + x^{n} \leq 2$$ and therefore $$\frac{x^{n}}{2} \leq \frac{x^{n}}{1 + x^{n}} \leq x^{n}\tag{1}$$ for all $x$ with $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Integrating the above with respect to $x$ on interval $[0, 1]$ we get $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}}{1 + x^{n}}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\,dx$$ or $$\frac{1}{2(n + 1)}\leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}}{1 + x^{n}}\,dx \leq \frac{1}{n + 1}\tag{2}$$ which is the inequality in the question. Using Squeeze theorem we now get $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}}{1 + x^{n}}\,dx = 0\tag{3}$$ Next we analyze the function $$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^{n}}{1 + x^{n}}$$ for $x \in [0, 1]$. Clearly we can see that $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0, 1)$ and $f(1) = 1/2$ so that $f$ is bounded on $[0, 1]$ and has a single discontinuity at $x = 1$. It follows that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$ exist and has the value $0$. Hence using $(3)$ we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}}{1 + x^{n}}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^{n}}{1 + x^{n}}\,dx\tag{4}$$ Note that the sequence of function $f_{n}(x) = \dfrac{x^{n}}{1 + x^{n}}$ converges pointwise to $f(x)$ on $[0, 1]$ but the convergence is not uniform (as noted by OP). But this does not necessarily mean that the expected identity $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}(x)\,dx\tag{5}$$ does not hold. Uniform convergence is *only a sufficient but not a necessary condition* for $(5)$ to hold and this question serves as a nice example to show that uniform convergence is not necessary for $(5)$ to hold.

---

**Note**: All the integrals used above are Riemann integrals. There is a deeper theory of Lebesgue integrals which gives very general conditions (much more widely applicable than uniform convergence) under which $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ and $\int_{a}^{b}$ operations can be interchanged (or we say these operations *commute*). It is possible to interpret these integrals in the question as Lebesgue integrals and then the desired equality of limit of integral and integral of limit is a direct consequence of [Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). But I don't think we need to use these tools to deal with the particular question here (at least the wording of the question does not seem to suggest anything about Lebesgue integration).

Comment: very nice (++++1)

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $f\in C[0,1]$ then for $n\geq 0$,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 x^n f(x^n)dx=0$$
In fact, let $M=\max_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|$, then
$$0\leq \left|\int_0^1 x^n f(x^n)dx\right|\leq  \int_0^1x^n | f(x^n)|dx 
\leq M\int_0^1x^n dx =\frac{M}{n+1}\to 0$$
as $n$ goes to infinity. By [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), the limit of $\int_0^1 x^n f(x^n)dx$ is zero.

P.S. As regards your inequality. We have that $1\leq 1+x^n\leq 2$ for $x\in[0,1]$. Hence
$$\frac{1}{2(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^n dx\leq
 \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}dx\leq \int_0^1 x^ndx =\frac{1}{n+1}$$
where we used the monotonicity of the integral: if $f(x)\leq g(x)$ in $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^b f(x)dx\leq \int_a^b g(x)dx$. Again by [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), the limit of the middle term is zero.

Comment: Quote: "Does anyone have ideas how to get this inequality and why it proves the question?"

Comment: @Did See my P.S.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$0\leqslant\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\leqslant 1  $$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and all $n$. Since $$\int_0^1 \mathsf dx = 1<\infty, $$
by dominated convergence we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,\mathsf dx = \int_0^1 \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\right)\,\mathsf dx. $$
The pointwise limit of $x\mapsto \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ is zero for $\in[0,1)$, so the above integral is zero.

Comment: We really don't need dominated convergence theorem to establish the identity here. Seems like an overkill.

Comment: It certainly is not necessary, but it is worth mentioning, considering the first approach that the OP took (uniform convergence $\implies$ integral and limit can be interchanged) is a direct result of dominated convergence.

Comment: Quote: "Does anyone have ideas how to get this inequality and why it proves the question?"

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$\frac{1}{2(n+1)} \le \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}dx \le \frac{1}{n+1}\implies\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}dx=0$$

by the squeeze theorem. Now just observe that for $\;x\in[0,1)\;$ ,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}=\frac0{1+0}=0$$

Fill in details now.

Comment: Quote: "Does anyone have ideas how to get this inequality and why it proves the question?" You are explaining "why it proves the question".

Comment: @Did Quote (and not less than the titile): "How to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}dx$ = $\int_0^1 \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}dx$?" , and yes: I am answering both what is in the title and also that why.

Comment: Dunno what you are playing at. No big deal anyway.